# How to replace variable in Blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

For example I have blade template:

```
$a = $parameter;

@if (count($parameter['children']) > 0)
   {{$a}}
@endif
```

How to put `$parameter['children']` above `if` to another variable? That to iterate this variable below in script

Comment: you can't init variable in blade file like this `$a = $parameter`, put your variable logic in controller and send it to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The philosophy behind blade is to remove any php or business logic from the front-end. It is not the responsibility of the view to do so.

You should only use control block (if, else, ifelse, foreach, etc.) and output what you need.

Any logic or behavior should be taken care of in the controller by passing objects that are correctly constructed to the view.

For example you could do something like this:

```
@if (count($children) > 0)
    @foreach($children as $child)
      {{ $child->a; }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```